# Jquery. Scrollbars on dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is filled with content dynamically and is fixed so it will always be in the same place even when you scroll. I need scrollbars to appear when the div is has too much content and goes beyond the screenborder.

Am i making sense?

//EDIT
Hmmm... i just realized im thinking wrong. I dont need scrollers. I need to resize the DIV so it wont reach under the bottom of the screen.

//EDIT
This was my sollution.

```
 function adjustPopupSizeToScreen() {
                //AFTER SETTING MESSAGE, CHECK IF DIV GOES BEYOND THE SCREEN AND ADJUST.

                var popupBottomPosition = PopUpBox.offset().top + PopUpBox.height();
                var browserBottomPosition = $(window).height();
                var popUpTopMarginToBrowserEdge = PopUpBox.offset().top;
                if (popupBottomPosition > browserBottomPosition) {
                }
                    PopUpBox.height(browserBottomPosition - 60);
                    MessageDiv.height(PopUpBox.height() -80);



            }
   //adjustPopupSizeToScreen()
            $(window).resize(function () {
                adjustPopupSizeToScreen();
            });
```

Comment: Doesn't that happens automatically?

Comment: Use the [overflow](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) property

Comment: Nope. :( 
Probably because the content is added dynamically through a JS funtion, so i figured that the scrollbars check for content overflow before the JS injects the content?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `.scroll()`

```
$('#divid').scroll(function() {

});
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Im not getting it. I need to check if the div is larger then the screen and then make it small enough to fit the screen and add scrollers. Hmmm... i just realized im thinking wrong. I dont need scrollers. I need to resize the DIV so it wont reach under the bottom of the screen.

Comment: you can specify the width and height of the div for the same